Unable to use Azcopy to copy all blobs from source to destination - error RESPONSE 403: 403 This request
I previously ran the command below and it worked fine, I did so by generating a SAS token for the storage account
.\azcopy.exe copy "https://source.blob.core.windows.net/?TOKEN" "https://destination.blob.core.windows.net/?TOKEN" --recursive
Doing so today, I get the errors
INFO: Authentication failed, it is either not correct, or expired, or does not have the correct permission PUT https://destination.blob.core.windows.net/mystore/b430/QID304086_202_92330_1.txt.snap
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ERROR CODE: CannotVerifyCopySource
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:ab63339f-501e-xxxx

Trying to work out what is different, surely the SAS token ought to have access to the storage account when I have ticked all services, blob, table, file etc.
Any ideas here ?

Detailed logs
.\azcopy.exe copy "https://mysource.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacux&se=2024-06-27T16:47:45Z&st=2024-06-06T08:47:45Z&sxxx" "https://mydestination.blob.core.windows.net/?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlacupx&se=2024-06-20T16:49:53Z&st=2024-06-06T08:49:53Z&xxxx" --recursive
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job c48655f7-62ac-c349-641e-86368637fd54 has started
Log file is located at: C:\xx\.azcopy\c48655f7-62ac-c349-641e-86368637fd54.log

INFO: Authentication failed, it is either not correct, or expired, or does not have the correct permission PUT https://mydestination.blob.core.windows.net/staging/3cea067bfe864ea8b31b84b62f053792/CSdfs_165345_0.txt.snappy
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ERROR CODE: CannotVerifyCopySource
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><Error><Code>CannotVerifyCopySource</Code><Message>This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
RequestId:4c3278e6-301e-0074-7bee-b776fb000000
Time:2024-06-06T08:50:56.3492318Z</Message></Error>
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

panic: send on closed channel

goroutine 3603 [running]:
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobMgr).SendXferDoneMsg(0x0?, {{0xc000013a20, 0xaa}, {0xc000013ad0, 0xac}, 0x0, 0xfffffffa, 0x778e, 0x0})
        D:/a/1/s/ste/jobStatusManager.go:72 +0x8f
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobPartMgr).SendXferDoneMsg(0x9c753e?, {{0xc000013a20, 0xaa}, {0xc000013ad0, 0xac}, 0x0, 0xfffffffa, 0x778e, 0x0})
        D:/a/1/s/ste/mgr-JobPartMgr.go:693 +0x74
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobPartTransferMgr).ReportTransferDone(0xc000117ab0)
        D:/a/1/s/ste/mgr-JobPartTransferMgr.go:992 +0x174
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.commonSenderCompletion({0x1004320, 0xc000117ab0}, {0x1ec84cb1468, 0xc000a04c30}, 0xc00009e420)
        D:/a/1/s/ste/xfer-anyToRemote-file.go:629 +0x429
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.epilogueWithCleanupSendToRemote({0x1004320, 0xc000117ab0}, {0x1ec84cb1468, 0xc000a04c30}, {0xff51e0, 0xc0008dad20})
        D:/a/1/s/ste/xfer-anyToRemote-file.go:584 +0x96a
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.anyToRemote_file.func1()
        D:/a/1/s/ste/xfer-anyToRemote-file.go:364 +0x31
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobPartTransferMgr).runActionAfterLastChunk(...)
        D:/a/1/s/ste/mgr-JobPartTransferMgr.go:663
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobPartTransferMgr).ReportChunkDone(0xc000117ab0, {{0xc000013a20, 0xaa}, 0x0, 0x778e, 0xc000cbef00, 0xc000cbef04})
        D:/a/1/s/ste/mgr-JobPartTransferMgr.go:649 +0x172
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.createChunkFunc.func1(0x5f5e100?)
        D:/a/1/s/ste/sender.go:193 +0x384
github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobMgr).chunkProcessor(0xc000954000, 0xc000cba5a0?)
        D:/a/1/s/ste/mgr-JobMgr.go:1063 +0xbd
created by github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/v10/ste.(*jobMgr).poolSizer
        D:/a/1/s/ste/mgr-JobMgr.go:965 +0x23d


What are the permissions included in the SAS tokens? Are you copying across different storage accounts?

SAS token expire?

The SAS token was set to expire a week from today's date, so I don't think its that. its complaining that the SAS token doesn't have authorisation for a PUT. This is despite selecting all the options when generating the token.


RESPONSE 403: 403 This request is not authorized to perform this operation.
ERROR CODE: CannotVerifyCopySource.

The above error when you don't proper permission to access the storage account.
In my environment, I have two different storage account with name venkat123 and venkat326.
In my source storage account(venkat123), I stored some files with container name test like below.
Portal:

SAS Token:
You can get the SAS token from the portal with permission read, write, list.

In the same way destination storage account(venkat326), I have a container name with sample and also, I created SAS token with read, write, list permissions.
Portal:

Now, using the same command it worked successfully in my environment.
Command and output:
PS C:\Users\xxx> azcopy copy "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net/test?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwltfx&se=2024-06-06T10:47:18Z&st=2024-06-06T02:47:18Z&spr=https&sig=ZjOTxxxxxxxJSoaSpUg%3D" "https://venkat326.blob.core.windows.net/sample?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=co&sp=rwltfx&se=2024-06-06T10:56:55Z&st=2024-06-06T02:56:55Z&spr=https&sig=dhbGNmwHoxxxxxxxx" --recursive
INFO: azcopy.exe 10.22.2: A newer version 10.24.0 is available to download

INFO: Scanning...
INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job 21c5028xxxxx39-74c54f99cebd has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\xxxx\.azcopy\2xxx7844-6539-74c54f99cebd.log

100.0 %, 4 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 4 Total,


Job 21c50282xxx4f99cebd summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0669
Number of File Transfers: 4
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Number of Symlink Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 4
Number of File Transfers Completed: 4
Number of Folder Transfers Completed: 0
Number of File Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Failed: 0
Number of File Transfers Skipped: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 2051
Final Job Status: Completed


Portal:
The above command executed successfully and copied files to destination container,

Reference:
Copy blobs between Azure storage accounts with AzCopy v10 | Microsoft Learn
Update
To copy between storage account I checked all resource type it worked successfully.

Command and output:
PS C:\Users\xxxx> azcopy copy "https://venkat123.blob.core.windows.net?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlytfx&se=2024-06-06T17:27:17Z&st=2024-06-06T09:27:17Z&spr=https&sig=ZZBi6GbMcJlgpq1ee1xxxxxxc0v%2BoXnPEc%3D" "https://venkat326.blob.core.windows.net?sv=2022-11-02&ss=bfqt&srt=sco&sp=rwdlytfx&se=2024-06-06T17:34:05Z&st=2024-06-06T09:34:05Z&spr=https&sig=RkuGcq6xxxxyApA4czQ%3D" --recursive
INFO: Scanning...
INFO: azcopy.exe 10.22.2: A newer version 10.24.0 is available to download

INFO: Any empty folders will not be processed, because source and/or destination doesn't have full folder support

Job 703523ad-20bb-1d4xxx9ce808 has started
Log file is located at: C:\Users\vxxx\.azcopy\703xxxb-1d4d-6aef-5daa1e9ce808.log

100.0 %, 2 Done, 0 Failed, 0 Pending, 0 Skipped, 2 Total,


Job 703523ad-xxxx5daa1e9ce808 summary
Elapsed Time (Minutes): 0.0669
Number of File Transfers: 2
Number of Folder Property Transfers: 0
Number of Symlink Transfers: 0
Total Number of Transfers: 2
Number of File Transfers Completed: 2
Number of Folder Transfers Completed: 0
Number of File Transfers Failed: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Failed: 0
Number of File Transfers Skipped: 0
Number of Folder Transfers Skipped: 0
TotalBytesTransferred: 987
Final Job Status: Completed

PS C:\Users\xxxx>



If you have a look at the screenshot with the edited question, I do not seem to have the option to tick Allowed blob index permissions. Could this be the reason ? The error says that it doesn't have PUT permissions on the destination storage account.

Are you trying between two different storage accounts?

Yes I have, I have been specific with the container name and not used recursive, its complaining about permissions but the screenshot above shows that i have chosen all the required options, not sure what other permissions need to be in place to generate a was token.

Please try my approach exactly and if you figured error please paste it here.

Tried your approach, included detailed logs at the bottom of the original question. please check.

Sorry, I checked all resource type https://i.imgur.com/rNmYlX0.png to copy entire storage account to another here is the successfully copied output https://i.imgur.com/yhpaxfP.png

Hope this address your issue.

Also updated in answer also.

We use private endpoints only, traffic cannot traverse the public endpoints.

Have you tried with updated procedure?
